# The overloaded member function is not found, the class is in header

Tags: c++

I got the error messages for functions in user.cpp file: overloaded member function  not found and in main.cpp I got : declaration is incompatible with function.
The program is a phonebook that writes data and takes from file. The functions are working individually, but when I put them in project calling them doesn't work.

Edit :
After editing of program it's working, but i made 3 new functions that don't work properly. First one is Prefix that search for a country in a file and return prefix for phone number, the return is good, but it's not saving in file. SearchUser and DeleteUser functions that work partially, in file stay the same users.

**user.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class User
{private:

    string firstname, lastname, country, city, street;
    string phone, prefix;

public:
  void ReadAllUsers(User[], int&);
  void SaveUser(User, int&);
  void SaveToFile(const User[], int);
  void AddName(User[], int&);
  void ListAllUsers(const User[], int&);
  void Prefix(User, int);
  void ChangePhone(User[], int&);
  void Help();
  void DeleteUser(User[], int&);
  bool Search(string x) 
{
return (phone.find(x) != string::npos);
}

};
```

**user.cpp**

```
#include "User.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;

const string PHONEBOOK_FILENAME = "phonebook.txt";
void User::Help()
{cout<<"\nWELCOME TO THE APPLICATION!\n";
 cout<<"Press 0 to display on the screen all records that are saved in the file(phonebook.txt)\n";
 cout<<"Press 1 to add 1 or more new record(s) in file(phonebook.txt)\n";
 cout<<"Press 2 to delete permanently a record from file(phonebook.txt)\n";
 cout<<"Press 3 to sort users from file(phonebook.txt) by name and display them on the screen\n";
 cout<<"Press 4 to edit a user phone number and save it after in file(phonebook.txt)\n";
 cout<<"Press 5 for help\n";
 cout<<"Press 6 to exit the application\n";
}

void User::ReadAllUsers(User people[], int &num_people)

{
    ifstream f;

    f.open(PHONEBOOK_FILENAME.c_str());

    if (f.fail())
{
  cout << "Unable to open file " << endl;
  return ;
}
    int i = 0;

    while (!f.eof() && i < 100)

    {   getline(f, people[i].firstname);
        getline(f, people[i].lastname);
        getline(f, people[i].phone);
        getline(f, people[i].country);
        getline(f, people[i].city);
        getline(f, people[i].street);
        i++;
    }
num_people = i;

f.close();

}

//Add country prefix to the phone number
void User::Prefix(User person, int num_people)
{string filecountry;
ifstream f;
    f.open("prefix.txt");
    {
    while (getline(f, filecountry))
  {
      if (person.country == filecountry )
      {
         f.ignore();//next line
         f >> person.prefix;
        }
    }
cout << "The prefix is " << person.prefix;
f.close();
  }
}
void User::SaveUser(User person, int &num_people)
{
ofstream f(PHONEBOOK_FILENAME.c_str(), ios::app ) ;
    if (f.fail())
    cout << "Unable to open file " << endl;
        else
            Prefix(person, num_people);
        f << person.firstname << " " <<  person.lastname << " " << person.country <<  " " << person.city << " " << person.street << " " << person.prefix << "-" << person.phone << endl;
cout << "\nThe user was added\n";
}
//Save data after a modification or after a user delete
void User::SaveToFile(const User people[], int num_people)

{ofstream f;
f.open(PHONEBOOK_FILENAME.c_str());

 for(int i = 0; i < num_people; i++)

    {

        f << people[i].firstname << " " << people[i].lastname << " " <<  people[i].country << " " << people[i].city << " " << people[i].street << " " << people[i].prefix << " " << people[i].phone << endl;
}
}
// Read user data from the keyboard, add a new contact to the array
void User::AddName(User people[],int &num_people)
{User person;

    cout <<"Enter the user's first name: ";
    cin >> person.firstname;

    cout <<"Enter the user's last name: ";
    cin >> person.lastname;

    cout <<"Enter the user's country: ";
    cin >> person.country;

    cout <<"Enter the user's city: ";
    cin >> person.city;

    cout <<"Enter the user's street: ";
    cin >> person.street;

    cout <<"Enter the user's phone number: ";
    cin >> person.phone;

        for(int i = 0; i < num_people; i++)

    {

        if( i + 1  == num_people)

            people[num_people] = person;

    }
SaveUser(person, num_people);

   num_people++;

}
// Ask the for person's name to change, find the person in the array and
// change it to the new phone number.  Then save the new data to file by
// calling SaveToFile.
void User::ChangePhone(User people[], int &num_people)
{
User person;
int count;

cout <<"Enter name to change: ";
cin >> person.firstname;

for(count = 0; count < num_people; count++)

    {

        if(people[count].Search(person.firstname))

        {   cout <<endl<< people[count].firstname<<endl;

cout <<"Current number"<<people[count].phone;
cout << "\nNew number: ";

cin >> people[count].phone;

SaveToFile(people,num_people);
cout <<"\n\nNew number Saved.";
return;
 }
}
if(count = num_people)

        cout <<"\nName not found.\n";

}

void User::DeleteUser(User people[], int &num_people)
{string phone;
int count = 0;
ifstream f;
f.open("phonebook.txt");
cout << "Input the phone of user that you want to delete ";
cin >> phone;

for(count = 0; count < num_people; count++)

    {

        if(people[count].Search(phone))

        {   cout <<endl<< people[count].phone<<endl;
people[count].firstname = people[count].lastname = people[count].phone = people[count].country = people[count].city = people[count].street = " ";
        }
SaveToFile(people,num_people);
cout <<"\n\nUser deleted.";
return;}
f.close();
}

// Ask the user for a name to find and show all occurrences of the name
// in the given array.
/*void SortUsers(User people[], int num_people)
{

}
*/
// Display all user data.
void User::ListAllUsers(const User people[], int &num_people)
{string line;
ifstream f;
f.open("phonebook.txt");
if (f)
    {
 while (getline(f, line)) {
    cout << line.c_str() << endl;
    }
}
  else
    cout << " Can't open the file!\n";
f.close();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "User.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
string mypassword; //file password
string password; //input password
char ch;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("mypassword.txt");
    file >> mypassword;
    file.close();
cout << "=====================================================================\n";
cout << "                               WELCOME !"<<endl;
cout << "=====================================================================\n";
cout << " Enter the password to access the program : ";
   ch = _getch();
   while(ch != 13){//character 13 is enter
      password.push_back(ch);
      cout << '#';
      ch = _getch();
}
cout << "\n=====================================================================\n";
if(password==mypassword)
{cout<<"\n Correct password!"<<endl;
 cout << "=====================================================================\n";
int choice;
bool menu = true;//menu
User people[100];
int num_people=0;
while (menu != false){
cout << "|===================================================================|\n";
cout << "|                                =MENU=                             |\n";
cout << "|===================================================================|\n";
cout << "|                            0 - Phone book!                        |\n";
cout << "|                            1 - Add user!                          |\n";
cout << "|                            2 - Delete user!                       |\n";
cout << "|                            3 - Sort users!                        |\n";
cout << "|                            4 - Edit user!                         |\n";
cout << "|                            5 - Help!                              |\n";
cout << "|                            6 - Exit!                              |\n";
cout << "|===================================================================|\n";
cout << " Enter your choice and press enter: ";
cin >> choice;
 User user;
 fstream file;
file.open("phonebook.txt", ios::ate | ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary );
// Get records from file
user.ReadAllUsers(people, num_people);

  switch (choice)
{
case 0://Read all contacts from file
{cout << "==============================PHONEBOOK==============================\n" << endl;

    user.ListAllUsers(people, num_people);
}
break;
case 1:
    {
    user.AddName(people, num_people);
break;}
case 2:
    {
    user.DeleteUser(people, num_people);
break;}
case 3:
    cout << "nothing\n";
break;
case 4:
    {
    user.ChangePhone(people, num_people);
break;}
case 5:
    {
    user.Help();
    break;}
case 6:
    {cout << " Session ended!\n";
file.close();
menu = false;
break;}

default:
    cout << " Not a Valid Choice. \n";
    cout << "======================================================================\n";
    cout << " Choose again.\n";
    cin >> choice;
break;
    }
  }
}
    else {
        cout<<"\n"<<" Wrong password!"<<endl;
        cout << "===================================================================\n";
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help with code errors, we like the askers to post a [mcve]: something which reproduces the error without additional code/data needed, but does not contain code unrelated to the error. What you've posted is far from minimal: most of it could be removed, in fact. Please reduce your code to an MCVE and then [edit] your question to only include that.

Comment: What is the exact error? What function is not found?

Comment: Your declaration says `void ReadAllUsers(User, int);` but your definition `void User::ReadAllUsers(User people[], int &num_people)`. Those do not match. Same goes for almost every other function. The definitions say `User people[]` and your declarations  `User &`.

Comment: `ReadAllUsers` is declared differently in user.h and user.cpp.  So are `AddName` and `ListAllUsers`.  Also, consider using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: same problem of inconsistency between declaration and definition for `User::SaveToFile` and `User::AddName` and `User::ListAllUsers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration in User.h and User.cpp are not consistent, supposing the implementation correct the declaration of the class can be replaced by :

```
class User
{
  private:
    string firstname, lastname, country, city, street, streetnumber;
    string phone;

public:
  void ReadAllUsers(User[], int&);
  void SaveUser();
  void SaveToFile(const User[], int);
  void AddName(User[], int&);
  void ListAllUsers(const User[], int&);
  void Read();
  void Print();
};
```

But the operation working on a vector of User must be static, they do not affect the instance.

```
class User
{
  private:
    string firstname, lastname, country, city, street, streetnumber;
    string phone;

public:
  static void ReadAllUsers(User[], int&);
  void SaveUser();
  static void SaveToFile(const User[], int);
  static void AddName(User[], int&);
  static void ListAllUsers(const User[], int&);
  void Read();
  void Print();
};
```

Why are you using array rather than *std::vector*, this last is much more practical

In *main*

- the local var *people* must be an array/vector, if an array considering the limitation to 100 in `User::ReadAllUser` it can be `User people[100];`, but again a vector is much better
- you redefine the variables *people* and `num_people` in some cases of the *switch*, that as no sense, these redefinitions must be removed. Using a vector the variable `num_people` become useless

The unique definition of the variables `people` and `num_people` (if array rather than vector) must be moved before the *while* rather than inside, and `num_people` if it exists must be initialize to 0, so

```
 ...
 int choice;
 bool menu = true;//menu
 User people[100];
 int num_people = 0;

 while (menu != false){
```

or

```
 ...
 int choice;
 bool menu = true;//menu
 vector<User> people

 while (menu != false){
```

But what about to make *people* a static variable of User, saving all the instances ?

In `User::ReadAllUsers`

> ```
> if (f.fail())
> {
>   cout << "Unable to open file " << endl;
> }
> else
> {
>    return ;
> }
> ```

has no sense, the return must be done in case you cannot open file file, not when you can, so :

```
if (f.fail())
{
  cout << "Unable to open file " << endl;
  return ;
}
```

You missed to check `file.open("mypassword.in");` success

Do not use literal number but character name, so '\r' rather than 13. Note `\r' supposes you are under Windows, under for instance a Linux you will read '\n' without '\r' before

*User::AddName* must be static and add a user in *people*, not just setting a local var. The call of `User::SaveUser()` must be done on the new instance, this is not even the case currently where the operation is not static

`User::SaveUser` must **add** a the new user in the file, not replace all the file with just the new user, open the file in append mode.

Comment: Error 1 error C2664: 'User::ReadAllUsers' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'User' to 'User []'

Comment: I have this error in main, but the the rest of it is ok, thanks again/.

Comment: @Imre_talpa that means you missed the change in the main

Comment: I put User people[100], is that you reffered ?

Comment: i see now, i will do the changes

Comment: user.ReadAllUsers(people[], num_people);

Comment: @Imre_talpa wait, I continue to check your program and there are other inconsistencies, for instance why do you not use/set the array of user ?

Comment: i should add something between parantheses ?

Comment: I got rid of all errors, but the function SaveUser() write over existing data in file, can you give a suggestion what to do ?

Comment: @Imre_talpa yes I noticed, I speak about that in my answer, read it again, yo uhave a lot of changes to do, I recommend you to use a std::vector rather than you array

Comment: @Imre_talpa I already given you several hints, is better for you to get them into account, you will learn much more doing yourself rather than looking at the result if I do myself, no ?